# iPhone app displaying distance of venue in the table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, userlocation

I have an app that lists a number of venues which have their latitude and longitudes stored in database. I populate the list with json. And then I display the result in a dynamic table. In the cells, I have distance in kilometers of the venue. I find this distance by getting users current location and calculating the distance with the venues coordinates.

It works fine but my problem is as the view loads, the distances are wrong until after 3-5 seconds when the user location is updated, it shows correct distances.

I get the user location and populate the cells in viewdidload.

My question is: is it possible to get the user's location in the previous view and pass it onto this view so that the distances shown are correct initially?

Here is the code:

I first get the user loc in viewdidload:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then further than I get my json data, etc. Then I do the tableView:

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [rows count];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    //    int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    //    double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    //    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    //    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    //    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
    //                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    latLabel.text = lat;
    //    degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    //    decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
    //    minutes = decimal * 60;
    //    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    //    NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
    //                       degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    longLabel.text = longt;

    //CGFloat Alat = [lat floatValue];
    //CGFloat Alon = [longt floatValue];
    self.aalat = lat;
    self.aalon = longt;

}



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    THELATITUDE = [dict objectForKey:@"L_LAT"];
    THELONGITUDE = [dict objectForKey:@"L_LON"];
    CGFloat Nlat = [THELATITUDE floatValue];
    CGFloat Nlon = [THELONGITUDE floatValue];
    CGFloat NNlat = [aalat floatValue];
    CGFloat NNlon = [aalon floatValue];
//    NSLog(@"lat1: %f", Nlat);
//    NSLog(@"Lon1: %f", Nlon);
//    NSLog(@"lat2: %f", NNlat);
//    NSLog(@"Lon2: %f", NNlon);
//    NSLog(@"aalat: %@", aalat);
//    NSLog(@"aalon: %@", aalon);


    CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Nlat longitude:Nlon];
    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:NNlat longitude:NNlon];
   // NSLog(@"Distance i meters: %f", [location1 getDistanceFrom:location2]);
    float mesafe1 = [location1 getDistanceFrom:location2 ] /1000;
    int x1 = mesafe1 * 100.0;
    float mesafe2 = (float) x1 / 100.0;


    //Create a string.
    NSString *strOne = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *strTwo = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *strThree = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *strFour = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *strFive = [[NSString alloc] init];


    //Append strings.
    strOne =  @"MESAFE: ";
    strTwo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0g", mesafe2];
    strThree = @" kilometre";
    strFour = [strOne stringByAppendingString:strTwo];
    strFive = [strFour stringByAppendingString:strThree];

    NSString *mesafe = strFive;


    cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"L_NAME"];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"LISTING_ID"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = mesafe;



    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: consider a different approach: show an indicator that the location is not yet available and update the table cells when it becomes available. Locating the user in the prev. view might lead to unnecessary activation of the gps module and battery usage.

Comment: Infact, after some more tests, I noticed that the correct distance is only shown when the cells are scrolled. Doesn't that mean, the user location is already available but for some reason, the correct distance is not seen until cells are scrolled. Do you suppose there is a logic error in the hierarchy of the coding? I'll post a bit by editing my post to show you the situation. in a bit.

Comment: I suppose that means you do not call [tableView reloadData] when you get a geolocation callback, try doing this at some point

Comment: I've put [tableView reloadData]; right at the end but that didn't make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the NSUserDefault method to save the user's current location latitude and longitude and use it your view. make location update manager is start not stop so you can get exactly latitude and longitude

use it when the user location update

```
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:latitude forKey:@"longitude"];
```

use it where you calculating distance

```
   NSString *lat = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"latitude"];
 NSString *long =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"longitude"];
```

Comment: Do I do this in appDelegate under applicationDidFinishLaunching? Would it be accessible in all views then?

Comment: Hiren, I went out this morning to test the accuracy of distances. So I started driving to the venues. I noticed that as I get close to venues, the distances won't update unless you scroll the table. When the venue goes off the screen and you scroll back to it, then it updates the distance change. Do you suppose it is possible to update it while the cell is in view and not being scrolled?

Comment: you have to reload the table every time. like you have to update your location manager

Comment: my location manager is set to start in the appdelgate. so it is updating the location. but where do I put the control to reload the table view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6084/discussion-between-hiren443-and-savas-zorlu)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the user's location in the previous view and then when loading the the listview send the data to the view like this (userLocation in this case can be a JSON string with long and latitude)

```
- (void) loadVenuesListView {
    VenuesViewController *venuesView = [[VenuesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VenuesViewController" bundle:nil];
    venuesView.userLocation = fetchedUserLocation;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:venuesView animated:YES];
    [venuesView release];   
}
```

Then in your VenuesViewController you have to make a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userLocation;
```